# Sending delete request in browser but getting error

Tags: node.js, express

**My delete route controller**

```
exports.deleteProduct = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const savedData = await CreateProduct.findOneAndDelete({_id: req.params.id });
        res.redirect('/admin-panel/products');
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400).send(error);
    }
}
```

**route for delete**

```
router.delete('/admin-panel/products/delete/:id',verifyJWT,getInfo,deleteProduct);
```

**route where it is redirecting**

```
router.get('/admin-panel/products',verifyJWT,getInfo,renderProdutsPage)
```

**error**

Cannot GET /admin-panel/products/delete/6342f2a5e8884cf054571479

When I am using get method I am getting result and even redirecting and I am using handlebars as frontend and I really need your help
When sending through postman , it is showing correct out put

Comment: need answer....

Comment: *Cannot GET*.. Looks like you are using the wrong method for the request.

Comment: this method do say that your are using GET request instead of DELETE in your frontend

Comment: There is a drop down in postman to select the request method. By default it is GET change it to DELETE and try